# Is it possible to generate webservices client code to a special package using apache cxf in maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate the webservices client once i build my project on the fly .. It currently does so but put it in package named based on the namespace of the WS.. so lets assume the name space is google.com , the generated files would be in com.google ..

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/ProjectWS?wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I want to generate the files to a different package.. lets call it comWS.gooleClient

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible using a custom binding or passing the `-p` extra argument as shown below:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/ProjectWS?wsdl</wsdl>
            <extraargs>
              <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
              <extraarg>com.something.else</extraarg>
            </extraargs>
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried `<extraarg>-p com.something.else</extraarg>` before finding your answer here and this did not work.

Answer (score 6):

I am very late though , but this specification worked for me

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.7</version>
 <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>generate-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
         <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
         <wsdlOptions>
               <wsdlOption>
              <wsdl>wsdl-location</wsdl>
          <extraargs>
            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
              </extraargs>
        <packagenames> 
                <packagename>desired location</packagename> 
        </packagenames> 
               </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>                    
       </configuration>
       <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this for extraarg?

```
<extraarg><!--namespace-->=<!-- new package name--></extraarg>
```

Example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
        <wsdlOptions>
          <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/ProjectWS?wsdl</wsdl>
            <extraargs>
                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                <extraarg>http://google.com=comWS.gooleClient</extraarg>
            </extraargs>
          </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```